# Bootstrap 2.2 accordion - content still visible after collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a very basic Bootstrap collapse. My code is taken from the Bootstrap docs (2.2) template.

However, when I click a title to collapse a section, the section slides up, but the content is still visible for 2-3 seconds before it disappears.

Since it was not consistent, I played around with it, and noticed it usually happens when the cursor is on top of the content after clicking the link that collapses the section.

Did anyone encounter this behaviour? Any ideas how to prevent this from happening?

My code:

```
   <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
      <div class="accordion-group" id="sec_productname">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
             <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion03" href="#collapse0301">Section1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse0301" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
                <!-- section 1 content goes here -->
          </div><!-- /end accordion-inner -->
        </div><!-- /end accordion-body -->
      </div><!-- /end accordion group -->
   </div><!-- /end accordion2 -->
```

Comment: try to remove your browser cache

Comment: you should upload to jsfiddle to get more help ;)

Comment: Can't get it to work (expand): http://jsfiddle.net/9h8Qx/ - It's my exact code, which works on my end.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Found the problem.

I had the following snippet in my code, I'm not quite sure where I got it from or why it's there (I swiped the layout from Bootstrap docs to save time, turns out- bad idea :)).

```
   $('.accordion-body.collapse').hover(
        function () {
        $(this).css('overflow','visible');
        }, 
        function () {
        $(this).css('overflow','hidden');
        }
);
```

Removing it solved the problem.